# Relationship between noderefernce fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-nodes

I have two content types: **Region** and **City**, `Region` node includes `City` node, every `City` node is related to some `Region` node, how I can create relationship for this situation: when I create `Region` node and refer a `City` node in a field, all `City` nodes have its `Region` referencing field set to this `Region` node and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) to achieve this.

Follow this steps:

1. Create two content types: **Region** and **City**.
2. Insert entity reference field: `Cities` in **Region** and `Region` in **City**.
3. Now enable [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) and update its configuration by going on your site: Configuration >> System >> Corresponding entity references.
4. Check this configuration: **Correspond Region on node(s) of type city with Cities on node(s) of type region.**
   [image]
5. Now in next tab **Updating existing entities** of entity type: **node**.
   [image]